# Asp.net MVC 4.0 : How to define seperate url for assets like JS, CSS and Images in Asp.NET MVC 4.0?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am newbiee in asp.net MVC 4.0, As I am developing a web application using it, my application is pulling correctly in debuging mode how ever when I am pulling it via IIS it is displaying the page contents but without CSS and JS.

For getting all the assets like CSS and JS to work on IIS, I have to define the baseurl of the application too.

Suppose my baseURL is http://localhost/myapp
Then, while defining the CSS path i have to mention the full path.

Like, http://localhost/myapp/css/style.css

Is there anyway to get rid out of it.

If I am not able to explain the question then please ask me to clear the concept, I will make it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use relative urls:

```
<link href="/myapp/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="/myapp/js/your.js"></script>
```

Optionally, you can use [System.Web.Optimization](https://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.aspnet.web.optimization/) helpers:

```
//Render styles:
@Styles.Render("~/myapp/css/style.css")
```

will render `<link href="/myapp/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">`

```
//Render scripts:
@Scripts.Render("~/myapp/js/your.js")
```

will render `<script src="/myapp/js/your.js"></script>`

If you are using [MVC bundling](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification) you can define custom urls for your assets:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/js/your.js").Include(
                 "~/myapp/js/your.js"));
}
```

and then in the View use it like this:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/js/your.js")
```

Comment: Hello @Alex Art, Thank You for writing the answer.

Comment: Hello @Alex Art, Thank You for writing the answer. How ever, I am Having  a problem using it because, If i am having multiple CSS files and JS files then, for each and every files, I have to define `@Styles.Render("~/myapp/css/style.css")`. Is there any other way like like We have in Any Php MVC Framework Eg. Codeigniter, Something like, We will define a Global Variable Named **base_url()** and if i have to call CSS1 then I will write **base_url("CSS1.css")**.

Comment: you don't need to define anything all the URLs are relative to the application root `@Styles.Render("~/myapp/css/style.css")` is used instead of `<link href="/myapp/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: But according to this method, If I will rename the application root folder i.e. myapp in @Styles.Render("~/myapp/css/style.css") to myapp1, then I must have to change the new name everywhere.

Comment: I thought that `myapp` is a folder inside your application. If it is a root then just use `@Styles.Render("~/css/style.css")`. As I said all URL are relative to your root

Comment: Actually myapp is root folder of the application.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the wayt as described by Alok Kumar Nikhil

But if you want something like : base_url("CSS1.css")

you could write a custom html-helper

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
    {
```

```
        public static IHtmlString BaseUrl<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, String FileName)
        {
                return MvcHtmlString.Create($"<Script src='/a/b/c/{FileName}'></Script>");
        }
    }
```

An use it in your view

@Html.BaseUrl("CSS1.css")

Comment: Thank you for writing @BrilBroeder, I will try it and Let you know.